# Call web-service before portlet render. Liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I have a portlet and i need call a web-service before the portlet render and put the result of this call in a field in the *jsp.

I try override the "render" and the "doView" method in the portlet class and call the web-service...OK,this work , but i cannot put the result in the *jsp because that method don't have a "ActionResponse" to do this.
How can I pass the result of call in the *jsp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the result of a web service call to a JSP, you can add the result to the request as a request attribute. Use the `<portlet:defineObjects />` tag in your JSP to make the request object available on the page. Then retrieve the object that you added to the request. E.g., you could use the following in your portlet's render method (assuming your portlet's render method takes `RenderRequest request` and `RenderResponse response` arguments):

```
request.setAttribute("myWebServiceResult", myWebServiceResult);
```

Then add the following to the top of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />
```

Then you can retrieve the request attribute like this:

```
Object myWebServiceResult = renderRequest.getAttribute("myWebServiceResult");
```

The `renderRequest` variable made available by the `<portlet:defineObjects />` tag is of type `javax.portlet.RenderRequest` which extends `javax.portlet.PortletRequest`. The `getAttribute(String)` method returns an `Object` but you can cast it to the type of the object that you attached in your portlet's render method.

For information about the `<portlet:defineObjects />` tag, see https://blogs.oracle.com/deepakg/entry/jsr286_defineobjects_tag